# How to execute a script on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a cookie only when a visitor clicks on the `Accept` button, but can't make the script execute on click. Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction(){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (s of scripts) {
        if (s.type == "text/plain") {
            s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            eval(s);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    # Some other scripts and title

    <script type="text/plain">
        document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
        alert();
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction();">
        Accept
    </button>
</body>
```

When I click on the button, I can see that the type of the script is changed from `text/plain` to `text/javascript`, but I didn't manage to execute the script after this, even with `eval()` (after inspecting the application's cookies, the new cookie is not created so I assume it was not executed).

I saw some other solutions on StackOverflow but they involved putting the content of the script I want to be executed in `myFunction()` and I don't want to do that (if possible).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your function is working, I have added alert in your code to check it and it's working, check the snippet

Comment: I don't think it's working, try executing the same thing but replace `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";` by `alert()`. When you click on the button, no alert is fired...

I edited the code snippet for that.

Comment: `eval(s)` makes no sense here, `s` does not contain JavaScript code in text form, it is a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: CBroe thanks for the information, do you know if there's a way to replace eval to execute `s`?

Comment: `eval(s.innerText)` would eval the _content_ of your script element. (And you don’t need to modify its type then either, because the script _element_ itself is not involved in the execution then any more, it just provides the “data”.)

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0);"` is absolutely pointless as well - `button` elements don’t _have_ a `href` attribute to begin with.

Comment: CBroes, noted. Thanks it seems to work now. Do you think using `eval()` might cause some security flaws in my application? If yes, is there some 'safer' alternatives to `eval()`. By the way, if you want you can make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you are in control of the script, then eval probably doesn’t do more damage, as if you had just embedded the script with `type="text/javascript"` to begin with. (Okay, _other_ scripts on the page could have _modified_ the text content of your script element by now maybe, but … how likely is that? Plus, then they could have probably done their “evil” on their own already.)

Comment: There might be other ways to solve this - but going into those more probably doesn’t make that much sense, before we don’t know _why_ placing this code inside a function is something you don’t want to do to begin with? That’s not a very “usual” requirement in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (s of scripts) {
    if (s.type == "text/plain") {
        //s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        eval(s);
    }
}
```

`eval(s)` does not make sense here, `s` does not contain JavaScript code in text form, it is a reference to the DOM element.

`eval(s.innerText)` would eval the content of your script element.

(And you don’t need to modify its type then either, because the script element itself is not involved in the execution any more, it just provides the “data”.)